# How to get a static IP address?

Tags: ip

I need to get a static IP address to access to a service that only allows specific IP (I can manage the whitelist).

The problem: my public IP is dynamic.

I'd like to :

- be able to activate this static IP only when needed (only during the time I need to access to the service)
- be able to activate this static IP at any place
- have a static IP which can't be used by other people than me

What are the different solutions to do so?

Comment: ""be able to activate this static IP at any place,"" meaning

Comment: I think it is better if you can post your requirement

Comment: type IPCONFIG /ALL (from Windows command prompt) or IFCONFIG (from an OS X Terminal) and look for either the Ethernet or Physical Address.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su], but your ISP would need to assign that to you, and that may require a business account.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from your ISP. But you will have to pay addition price.

1. You have to block using firewall when it is not needed.
2. static ip can only be at one place.
3. No one can use your own IP address.

I just provide answers. But i am not clear that what  your requirement is.

Comment: Very few ISPs these days offer static addresses to residential customers. And none of them are "portable". (dialup style pppoe might, but that's just as rare.)